# tkinter askdirectory syntax

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question about the `askdirectory()` in tkinter. Is it posible to use that function and also se what´s inside the folder that i want to select the directory from?

Because now when i use the function i can open the explorer and get the directory path to the folder i need but i can´t se what the folder contains (I just now that now before hand for now)... With the `askdirectory` function the folder says "No items match your search.". So i came up with this:

```
 filepath_ask = filedialog.askdirectory(
                initialdir=os.path.dirname(filedialog.askopenfilename(title ="Pick a folder in directory with .log files")),
                title = "Press 'Select Folder'")
```

But it´s not that "user friendly". First it opens a window with `askopenfilename` so that i can see the content in the folder, then it closes when i select a file and opens a new window with `askdirectory` to "Select Folder" that has the content/file i chose in the window before. There must be a better way? I have been reding upp on the dokumentatin but can´t find anything that works. Help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you think that it isn't as much of a bother to have the user select a file in the `askopenfilename` dialog, then why not just run with that (and skip `askdirectory` altogether):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pathlib

root = tk.Tk()
ask = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select a directory", filetypes = [("log",".log"),("All Files",".*")])
print(f"User selected Directory: {pathlib.Path(ask).resolve().parent}")
root.destroy()
```

Comment: Because i only need the filepath "C:/Users//Desktop/logfiles/*.log" not the filepath + file "C:/Users/Desktop/logfiles/file_test.log" so then i would have to cut the last part of, and that could be a sulotion. @ReidBallard

Comment: Correct, that's why I used Path.parent to get the directory.